# UIActionsheet delegate method calling twice in ios8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios8

In ios8 delegate methods of UIActionSheet calling multiple times

```
  - (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

I have checked in ipad 2 with IOS 8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its a bug of the ios 8..

As the @rob said `UIActionSheet` is deprecated in iOS 8. (UIActionSheetDelegate is also deprecated.)

To create and manage action sheets in iOS 8 and later, use `UIAlertController`

Comment: ugh, iOS 8.0.x has got to be the buggiest iOS release since...what, iOS 4.0?

Answer (score 4):

This is indeed the current behavior that I've seen reported in several places. It does appear to be a bug and hopefully will be fixed soon but no way to know for sure.

Answer (score 2):

You should UIAlertController to replace all AlertView and ActionSheet in iOS8.
If your target lower than iOS8, then you should check version and add more code

For example, this code is for iOS8 ActionSheet

```
-(void)testActionSheet{
    UIAlertController* alertAS = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Test ActionSheet"
                                                                   message:nil
                                                            preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

    UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Action" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                          handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                              NSLog(@"Action");
                                                          }];
    [alertAS addAction:defaultAction];
    UIAlertAction *cancleAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

    }];
    [alertAS addAction:cancleAction];
    [self presentViewController:alertAS animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to continue using the existing API, there is a bit of behavior that lets you know when to run your code and when to ignore the delegate call - the `buttonIndex`.

The first time the delegate methods are called, they are always passed the correct `buttonIndex`. The second time through, however, they are called with a `buttonIndex` of the cancel button.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately UIActionSheet is deprecated in iOS 8:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. One workaround: Use `actionSheet.tag`. Set it to a valid number (it will be 0 by default) such as 1, 2, ... while instantiating. Handle the response in:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

Check if it is valid (ex: not -1 before handling it). Once the response is handled here, before returning, set:

```
actionSheet.tag = -1;
```

This ensures that you will ignore it, although the second call is made. This works in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add: UIAlertController is the correct way to now to use UIAlertViews in iOS8.0+ (as UIAlertView is deprecated) however the bug of being able to select multiple options is somewhat mitigated.

The separate options in the alert view CAN be selected/highlighted at the same time, but the delegate method only seems to fire off one of them. Which one actually triggers off is undetermined, but I can confirm only one is fired off despite two/or more being highlighted if you use multiple fingers.